# Returning values from capacitor Android plugin does not work

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have a simple capacitor plugin with the cli generated `echo` method.

While I can access the arguments supplied from webview in the Java code, I can't seem to return values from the plugin back to webview.

```
    // Java Plugin method
    @PluginMethod()
    public void echo(PluginCall call) {
        String value = call.getString("value");

        JSObject ret = new JSObject();
        value = implementation.echo(value);
        ret.put("value", value);
        Logger.debug("MyPlugin.echo - ret: " + ret.toString());
        call.resolve(ret);
    }

    // Ionic app code
    MyPlugin.echo({ value: "Hello world!" })
    .then(res => {
      console.log('MyPlugin.echo success, res:', res);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log('MyPlugin.echo error:', err);
    });
```

Capacitor module versions:

```
    "@capacitor/android": "^3.0.0-rc.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "^3.0.0-rc.0",
```

What am I missing?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the root cause.

The issue is with Android Emulator with API 25. With this version of Android, capacitor plugin API call's response values do not seem to be marshalled to the caller.

I then tried emulators with API 26 & API 27. Same problem.

Lastly I tried an emulator with the latest API, level 30. This works fine.

Seems like Capacitor Android native plugin interface has issues with older API levels. May be this is a known issue.

EDIT: Further investigations have shown that this is not an issue with the Capacitor interface per se. Instead it has to with console.log messages not being captured by Android Studio log window (or adb logger). If you use Chrome developer tools to inspect the device, you do get the console.log messages as expected.